# JavaScript OOP access "sibling's" property through parent

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop, inheritance

I am wondering if it's possible to access properties of instance through it's parent class in JS.

To better understand what I am trying to achieve - I have a Game class that will act like a game loop with players and stats:

```
class GameObject {
    constructor(gameMap) {
        this.gameMap = gameMap
    }

    init() {
        let player1 = new Player(this.gameMap, 'Alice', {x: 10, y: 20})
        let player2 = new Player(this.gameMap, 'Bob', {x: 50, y: 80})
        this.players = [player1, player2]
    }

    playGame() {
        this.players.forEach(player => player.play())
    }
}
```

And the Player class will inherit from the GameObject:

```
class Player extends GameObject {
            constructor(gameMap, name, position) {
                super(gameMap)
                this.name = name
                this.position= position
            }
    
            play() {
                // some functionality here...
                this.getOpponentPos()
            }
    
            getOpponentPos() {
                let opponentName;
                let opponentPosition; // how to access player1 from player2 and player2 from player1 ??
                console.log(`${opponentName} is currently at: ${opponentPosition}`)
                    }
                }
            }
```

In other piece of code I will use the Game class in some game loop that will run continuously:

```
let myGame = new GameObject('oldTown')
myGame.init()
// some loop wraps this:
while (true) {   
    myGame.playGame()
}
```

My question is, how can I access player1 properties (position property in this matter) from player2 and player2 properties from player1 inside the class itself? How can I use the GameObject class players array (`this.players` in GameObject) to get each instance properties separately (and their values will change all the time)?

I know I can pass to the Player class the GameObject instance in the constructor like so:

```
class Player extends GameObject {
            constructor(gameMap, name, position, gameObj) {
                super(gameMap)
                this.name = name
                this.position = position
                this.currentGame = gameObj
            }
same code...
```

and instantiating it in the GameObject class code:

```
let player1 = new Player(this.gameMap, 'Alice', {x: 10, y: 20}, this)
let player2 = new Player(this.gameMap, 'Bob', {x: 50, y: 80}, this)
```

And acces the 'currenGame' in each instance but it does not use the inheritance capabilites and also in my head it leads to an infinite problem:

```
myGame ---
         |--- player1 ---
         |              |--- myGame ---
         |                            | --- player1 --- myGame --- and so on...
         |                            | --- player2 --- myGame ---
         |
         |--- player2 ---
         |              |--- myGame ---
         |                            | --- player1 --- myGame --- and so on...
         |                            | --- player2 --- myGame ---
```

Is this really a problem?

How can it be solved efficiently with the inheritance capabilities and super()?

I am very confused so if someone can clarify it to me I will be thankful!

Comment: Why would a `Player` extend from `Game`? There is no `is a` relation here: players are not "a more specific kind of game", so you almost certainly want to change your hierarchy here if you want your code to adhere to OO practices.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it can be a gameObject that inherits from a gameLoop that holds the gameObjects array, and I need to access each gameObject from the other

Comment: @Niv Then let it inherit from a `GameObject` class, but not from `Game`!

Comment: The game should have players. The players should be able to perform operations in the game, but not know if there operations affect any other player, or even if there are other players. It's the game who decides if an operation performed by a player affects any of the other players and it's the game who decides if the game is over and which player(s) have won. i.e. `checkIfWin` is not a method that makes sense on a player.

Comment: @Adam Right, I changed the checkIfWin to different method that should make more sense now just for the example.

Comment: @Niv `getOpponentPos` doesn't make sense either - reread my comment. A player doesn't even know it has an opponent. You can consider injecting the game into the player and have the player ask it's game to give you the positions of it's players. Or, I guess maybe you can even have the game inject the opponent into a player as well depending on how you want to structure it.